# Query all documents for last 10 minutes by ObjectId timestamp

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Im trying to get all documents fro the last 10 minutes. I thought it wold be convenient to use ObjectId for it. I`m using this code to achieve it.

```
currentTime := time.Now().UTC()
queryTime := currentTime.Add(-10 * time.Minute)
var oidtime = bson.NewObjectIdWithTime(queryTime)
query := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$gt": oidtime}}
err := c.Find(query).All(&result)
```

But I always have null as an answer.

```
err := c.Find(bson.M{}).All(&result)
```

This kind of query works fine though. 
I have this thing in mongo logs.

```
command: find { find: "meraki", filter: { _id: { $gt: "\�D�        " } }, skip: 0, $db: "devices" } planSummary: IXSCAN {
_id: 1 } keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:118 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 0ms
```

updated: Document example

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb464aff3276d5fa21cd31d"), "lldp" : *, "cdp" : null, "id" : "*"}
```

Comment: Are you sure `_id` is of type `ObjectId` in your database? Can you post an example document?

Comment: Your query works for me. Are you sure collection name is correct? Are you sure you have records inserted in the last 10 minutes? Please do note that the logic that inserts documents may not generate ObjectID's that use the current time!

Comment: @icza, once i change query to bson.M{} it works fine. So collection name is ok. I`m inserting data right before querying, i also tried to query data for last 24 hours. May the problem be in timezones?

Comment: The time part of the `ObjectId` is the time-zone independent Unix timestamp. Please show how the records are inserted to your db.

Comment: @icza, Tried both by db.insert from the shell and ` c := session.DB(r.database).C(source)
 err := c.Insert(rawInt...)`, where rawInt is a slice on interface{}

Comment: Again, your example works for me. If you want help, you need to show us a code that reproduces the problem. Aim for a [mcve].